# Force Safari to enable autoplay

Tags: safari, video, settings, bug, web-browser

Since last update (Ventura 13.1), my Safari does not seem to autoplay videos anymore.

I already tried to "allow all autoplay" or to disable all content blockers, but I still can't enable autoplay.

Since other users on the same version told me that they don't have this problem, does any of you know where that could come from ?

Here's an example of how all videos are now displayed :

[image]

Comment: To be more specific, it only happens on Safari, other browsers work perfectly fine

Comment: Does it happen if you create a new user account and test there?

Comment: Yes, it happens with a newly created account, but not for guest users